# Using IFELSE function across multiple columns

Tags: r, if-statement

I want to create a new column based on multiple columns of different data types

| Names | 1 | 2 | 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 000 | NA | 030 |
| B | 100 | DDD | NA |
| C | XXX | 000 | 050 |

Based on column 1-3, I want to add another column with the condition If value >= 30 then 1 else 0.

Output will be:

| Names | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 000 | NA | 030 | 1 |
| B | 100 | DDD | NA | 1 |
| C | XXX | 000 | 015 | 0 |

Note : There are 36 such columns (1-36) across where I want to use the if condition and then create a new column.

adding some more details:

These variables are extracted from one long string like "030060000XXX010" which turned into 030 , 060, 000, XXX, 010. Now using IFELSE condition if any of the value (number looking) is >= 30 then 1 else 0

Comment: Your columns are `character`, you're intending to do a numeric comparison of strings? How does `"DDD"` compare to `30`? Is it that *any* of the number-looking columns are greater than 30?

Comment: Since you want to do this programmatically (and not type in each of the 36 columns), is there a way that columns 1-3 are clearly grouped together by name?

Comment: @r2evans - yes I only want to compare the numeric looking columns and ignore the character ones.

Comment: @r2evans - These variables are extracted from one long string like "030060000XXX010"
which turned into 030 , 060, 000, XXX, 010. 

Now using IFELSE condition if any of the value (number looking) is >= 30 then 1 else 0

Comment: Are those your real column names, 1 2 and 3? (Did you force R to use nonstandard names? Typically R won't allow a column name to start with a number.) Again, is there a way to easily group them together by name, or is it just pray that the column-order is unchanged and go based on index number?

Comment: column order or name of the variables are not relevant.. I just want to check a simple condition against list of variables at once and then store a value based on that condition in a new column. 

These column names were generated a by a code I used to split them into equal groups of 3 from a long string. 

y <- strsplit(scrub_accounts$`DPD - HIST`, "(?<=...)", perl = TRUE)

scrub_accounts1 <- cbind(scrub_accounts, do.call(rbind, lapply(y, "[", seq_len(max(lengths(y))))))

Answer (score 2):

Consider using `if_any`.  Loop over the columns other than 'Name', create a logical condition after converting to integer class, replace the NA with `FALSE` and coerces the logical output from `if_any` to binary (`+`)

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df1 %>% 
    mutate(new = +(if_any(-Names, ~ replace_na(as.integer(.) >= 30, FALSE)  ) ))
```

Comment: thanks @akrun , worked like a charm. Just one follow up question, if instead of variable "Names" there are like 15 other variables (all numeric) which I would like to exclude from this calculation, is there a way to mention them without manually writing each of them down.

Comment: @RakshitSinghal you can use position index or range from one column to last one which you want to remove if they are all adjacent i..e `if_any(-(Names:somecol),` or use indexing i.e. `if_any(-(1:7),` or if they are not adjacent `if_any(-c(1:3, 5:7)` etc.

Answer (score 1):

Since you want to group by 3, one way is to `split.default` the columns by 3, operate on one three-pack at a time, then combine them later.

I'll demonstrate on the data but repeating the three data columns so that we can show the iteration.

```r
dat <- structure(list(Names = c("A", "B", "C"), X1 = c("000", "100", "XXX"), X2 = c(NA, "DDD", "000"), X3 = c(30L, NA, 50L), X1 = c("000", "100", "XXX"), X2 = c(NA, "DDD", "000"), X3 = c(30L, NA, 50L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))

split.default(dat[,-1], (seq_along(dat)[-1]-2) %/% 3)
# $`0`
#    X1   X2 X3
# 1 000 <NA> 30
# 2 100  DDD NA
# 3 XXX  000 50
# $`1`
#   X1.1 X2.1 X3.1
# 1  000 <NA>   30
# 2  100  DDD   NA
# 3  XXX  000   50
```

With this, we'll work on one three-pack at a time.

```r
func <- function(x, lim = 30) {
  x <- as.matrix(x)
  x <- `dim<-`(suppressWarnings(as.numeric(x)), dim(x))
  cbind(x,(+(rowSums(x <= lim, na.rm = TRUE) > 0)))
}
lapply(split.default(dat[,-1], (seq_along(dat)[-1]-2) %/% 3), func)
# $`0`
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
# [1,]    0   NA   30    1
# [2,]  100   NA   NA    0
# [3,]   NA    0   50    1
# $`1`
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
# [1,]    0   NA   30    1
# [2,]  100   NA   NA    0
# [3,]   NA    0   50    1
```

Now we just need to recombine them all again:

```r
do.call(cbind, c(list(dat[,1,drop=FALSE]), lapply(split.default(dat[,-1], (seq_along(dat)[-1]-2) %/% 3), func)))
#   Names 0.1 0.2 0.3 0.4 1.1 1.2 1.3 1.4
# 1     A   0  NA  30   1   0  NA  30   1
# 2     B 100  NA  NA   0 100  NA  NA   0
# 3     C  NA   0  50   1  NA   0  50   1
```